# ip address inet 127.0.0.1 changed unwillingly to 172.27.28.124 (Ubuntu 20.10 without netplan)

Tags: ubuntu, ip, ip-address, ubuntu-20.04

Below you can se the address 172.27.28.124 being used for lo.
However the address was a few hours ago 127.0.0.1, this is the good value. This should not be changed.

Could you please advice on how to investigate this issue ?

- Why would the ip addr change automatically ?
- Is there a way to log who what changing it ?

```
 ubuntu@xxx:~$ ip ad
    1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 172.27.28.124/32 scope global lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fd00::b:1c7c/128 scope global
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```